# Set Session ID from ASP.NET Core server to browser

Tags: asp.net-core, security, authentication, browser

During login, I need to set a session id in the browser so that all calls can be validated from the server.

Currently, the browser is sending a value that is set by default and not able to change it from the server.

I need to control the login from the server-side, not the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, session is managed by the server-side apps not the client app. When the server called the session set string method. It will generate the session id and let the client browser cookie to store it. When the client send the request, it will automatically send the session id and the server could check the session data by using session id. The session id is auto generated, but it will not change until the cookie expired. Besides, the Session cookies are deleted when the browser session ends.

According to your requirement, you want to set a session id in the browser so that all calls can be validated from the server. I suggest you could directly using the set session method to set the session with the right key and name.

When the client wants to login in, after login in successfully, I suggest you could call this method     `HttpContext.Session.SetString("User", "Username");`. Then you could check the session name inside your web application to validate the client user.

Comment: A single user can login from multiple devices also here. So setting it based on user name is not going to work in case of multiple logins.

Comment: The ID could be set by yourself. You could add more things inside that session, like clinet IP or else.